# How to deploy JSP project on heroku?

Tags: git, jsp, heroku

I want to deploy JSP project on heroku and I am using mysql database in this project, So how we can deploy this on heroku with mysql database.

Comment: Currently working on the exact same problem, is your mysql database local or over a network ?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Migrate your app to use postgres instead and use [Heroku Postgres](http://postgres.heroku.com).
2. Use [the amazon RDS addon](https://addons.heroku.com/amazon_rds).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Xeround’s add-on on Heroku. They offer a highly available MySQL cloud DB service that can be used with Heroku applications. I think you can create your DB from Heroku or from the DB service. Also because it is not an Amazon product you will be able to migrate away from the Amazon cloud in the future, e.g. to RackSpace.